# Design dynamic RDLC programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is it possible to design reports programmatically in winforms? Like putting textboxes, images, and all sorts of stuffs in a report as per the user requires.

My report currently looks like this:
[image: Report1.rdlc]

However, I would like to make the user to add things what they want using checkboxes that I will provide in the form. For example, an image header of their choice, textbox with their defined text, etc.. I've searched through the Internet but all of them are just for creating dynamic tables.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible to generate RDLC programmatically. It's just XML. There are [some articles](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/705248/generating-rdlc-dynamically-for-the-report-viewer) [out there](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170667(v=sql.90).aspx) on programmatically generating a report.

However, there's a lot of complexity that you might have to wade through.

Based on your screenshot, there might be a better way. It appears that you are trying to generate a quiz. Based on that, you could build a UI that allows someone to add questions of various types and then save them to a table. (Assuming a database backend, but your screenshot looks like SSRS, so I'm going down that route) What I've done in the past is to save a representation of each question as JSON. You end up with a couple of metadata columns, and then a `nvarchar(MAX)` column for the JSON. This allows a wider variety of question types without needing a lot of complexity in your table structure.

In the actual report definition (I use Visual Studio) you can write queries that extract the JSON and format it as a table for SSRS to consume. If you have at least SQL Server 2014, there is some native JSON functionality in T-SQL. We combine this with some logic in the report, some sub-reports to handle specific meta types, and some [HTML content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/importing-html-into-a-report-report-builder-and-ssrs). For a quiz with many questions, you can do the minimum querying to build the basic structure, and the loop over each record and extract more specific data about each question, be it multiple choice, text, etc.

## Update

Since you're only doing multiple choice, I would try a much simpler approach. You just need two tables: questions and choices. At that point, it's fairly trivial to [configure a tablix to do what you want](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/create-a-stepped-report-report-builder-and-ssrs).

Comment: Yes, I'm creating a multiple-choice exam paper generator. The body part (which contains the questions and distractors) is fine and can be left as is since it's a table that is going to be filled with whatever I have in the DataTable. The header part (Name, Section, etc.) is what I would like to be dynamic. I'm going to read the links you mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: If it's only multiple choice, I would go with the second option. You don't even need JSON. Programmatically building this is way overkill and hard to maintain.